# Setting different delay for loading indicator vaadin 8

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

In our app we have `getLoadingIndicatorConfiguration().setFirstDelay(1500)`
But in some places logo appears not in 1,5s but later about 4s or more. When we tried setting delay less value we observed logo appearing after entering any symbol in text fields where we have `valueChangeListener` or make `refreshAll` for grid. So how it works: for example delay is 300ms -> we enter some text to field -> interrupt -> request is sent to server side -> it takes more then 300ms -> logo appears. So we set delay 1500ms. But it lead to the problem I described at the beginning.

My question is if it is possible to set different delay for different layouts or elements?

Probably someone knows in detail how logo works?
I think It should work in the following way: after button click logo should appear and request and other things are done in background and only after we got response and done other things logo disappears. But, it seems to me that request and logo are run in parallel. I mean that when we click button -> timer run for logo starts -> request is sent -> timer end -> but logo appear after 4s or 5s or 6s, but not after 1.5s and I don't know why

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are actually looking for, but have you checked this another question about the same topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69721395/how-to-set-vaadin-8-loadingindicatorconfiguration-in-a-button-click

Comment: @TatuLund first of all I saw this link before and it is absolutely not what I'm looking for but thanks anyway. And, I want to know why I have delay before logo appearance 4(sometimes more) seconds when I have configuration that set up 1.5s. Right now I found that after receiving response grid is being updated and it seems to block the logo. And if it possible I want to know how exactly it works.